# In R, adding T prefix to tie ranks

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

```
data.frame(a = c(12, 13, 17, 19, 17), b = c(3, 5, 5, 4, 6)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(a_rank = rank(desc(a), ties.method = "min"), 
                b_rank = rank(desc(b), ties.method = "min")) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(a_rank)

   a b a_rank b_rank
1 19 4      1      4
2 17 5      2      2
3 17 6      2      1
4 13 5      4      2
5 12 3      5      5
```

How to update the code above to convert `a_rank` into a string column and add a `T` prefix to any ranks that are ties.

```
   a b a_rank b_rank
1 19 4      1      4
2 17 5     T2     T2
3 17 6     T2      1
4 13 5      4     T2
5 12 3      5      5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use an `ifelse` statement along with `duplicated` to find all the duplicated values and if they are duplicated then paste `T` to those values.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(a = c(12, 13, 17, 19, 17), b = c(3, 5, 5, 4, 6)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(a_rank = rank(desc(a), ties.method = "min"),
                b_rank = rank(desc(b), ties.method = "min")) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(a_rank) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("rank"), ~ ifelse(duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE), paste0("T", .),.)))
```

**Output**

```
   a b a_rank b_rank
1 19 4      1      4
2 17 5     T2     T2
3 17 6     T2      1
4 13 5      4     T2
5 12 3      5      5
```